# How would I add to an integer within a dict?

Tags: python

```
test = {"poop":{"okay":[10]}}
print(test)
```

For example, I want the 10 within["okay"], to now be 20.

Comment: `test['poop']['okay'] = 20`?

Comment: I can't hardcode, I need to add to whatever integer is in there.

Comment: @Br3xin what do you mean by add???

Comment: like var += 10  <<<<

Comment: You said you want that number "to now be 20".  Sounds like hardcoding to me...

Comment: "For example" Sorry 4 lack of detail, read my above comment

Comment: @Br3xin update the question accordingly. It's for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use square brackets to perform a look up on each level, then once you're at the `10` you can update it.

```py
>>> test = {"poop":{"okay":[10]}}
>>> test
{'poop': {'okay': [10]}}

>>> test['poop']
{'okay': [10]}

>>> test['poop']['okay']
[10] # note that this is a list w/ 1 element

>>> test['poop']['okay'][0]
10

# put it all together, let's add 10 to the value
>>> test['poop']['okay'][0] += 10
>>> test
{'poop': {'okay': [20]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```py
# To update the value in the list
test["poop"]["okay"][0] = 20

# Replaces the list altogether
test["poop"]["okay"] = 20
```